# IOS App logo assets

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

Can we use logo of youtube or netflix in our Iphone Application to mention some functionality?
will it be any issue over the app submission to appstore?

Comment: Why are you asking this on stackoverflow? It's not programming related at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question as defined in the Help Center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we use logo of youtube or netflix in our Iphone Application to mention some functionality?

YouTube has [a form for requesting permission to use it's brand](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/brand_request?hl=en-GB), so it's easy to just ask for permission. That seems like the right thing to do, and then if there's any problem with your app submission related to use of the logo, you can show that you have permission. I expect the same would be true of Netflix, though I haven't gone looking.